# How to efficiently vectorize (i.e. avoid explicit loops) a mapping of some colours into others in a Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, mapping

I have as input a Numpy matrix of rank three (i.e. an image: horizontal, vertical and 4 color channels). I want to read this matrix element-wise in their first two indices and map only certain colours into others, defined in respective arrays. The performance is very important, as this mapping will be applied many times, possible becoming a bottleneck of the program.

Precisely the code I have so far is:

```
# data is the rank-3 Numpy array with the image (obtained using the library PIL)
# palette has shape (11, 4) and defines the 11 colours to map
# palette_grey has shape (11,) and defines the 11 tones of grey to apply

for i in range(palette.shape[0]):  # loop in colours
    match = (data[:,:,0] == palette[i,0]) & (data[:,:,1] == palette[i,1]) & (data[:,:,2] == palette[i,2]) # build matrix only True when a given pixel has the right color
    for j in range(3): # loop to apply the mapping to the three channels (because it's just grey, so all channels are equal)
        data[:,:,j] = np.where(match, grey_palette[i], data[:,:,j]) # the mapping itself
```

Although the main task is vectorized (via np.where), there are still two explicit loops I'd like to avoid to improve performance.

Any idea to achieve this?

EDIT:

I have tried to remove the second loop (in channels) by defining the both palettes to have the same shape (11,4). Then, I have tried this:

```
for i in range(palette.shape[0]):
    match = (data[:,:,0] == palette[i,0]) & (data[:,:,1] == palette[i,1]) & (data[:,:,2] == palette[i,2])
    data[:,:,:] = np.where(match, grey_palette[i], data[:,:,:])
```

But it raises the error:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes
> (480,480) (4,) (480,480,4)

I guess this is the expected behaviour, but I thought the mapping I propose is unambiguous, and therefore doable by Numpy.

Comment: Honestly, this is as efficient as it's going to get without diving into C. You can maybe try to wrap the thing in `numba` and see if it helps, but your outer loops are honestly fine.

Comment: Actually, there's one more thing that you could check and that'd be `cv2`.

Comment: At a glance, I can tell that this can be done without any loops at all, with simple broadcasting. However, a single outer loop would be the most ideal solution.

Comment: What is the dtype and actual shape of the arrays? If you have uint8, with shape rows x cols x 4, you can do some optimization here

Comment: @orlp. You can do major improvements to this.

Comment: You can make a vectorized function with `numpy.vectorize` but it won't really improve performance, it'll just let you write shorter vectorized code.

Comment: Also you can reshape one of your arrays from (480, 480) to (480, 480, 1) with x[...,np.newaxis], then the dimensions will match for broadcasting.

Comment: @BatWannaBe. Please see my answer. I've posted two fully vectorized solutions. One uses broadcasting and one uses sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that you have an `(M, N, 4)` array of `uint8` values. You can view it as an array of 32-bit integers like this:

```
idata = data.view(np.uint32)
```

Secondly, you can convert your gray map to a proper `(K, 4)` array from a `(K,)` array:

```
grey = np.repeat(grey[:, None], 4, axis=-1)
```

While you're at it, you can convert it to integers as well as the palette:

```
ipalette = palette.view(np.uint32).squeeze()
igrey = grey.view(np.uint32).squeeze()
```

Now you have an `(M, N, 1)` image and `(K,)` palette and grey map. For sufficiently small `K`, you can do something like this:

```
ind = np.nonzero(idata == ipalette)
idata[ind[0], ind[1], 0] = igrey[ind[-1]]
```

This will write the grey values through directly to the original `data` array. The mask `idata == ipalette` broadcasts to `(M, N, K)`. `np.nonzero` returns the indices along each axis. The first two indices are the coordinates of matches in the image, while the third index is exactly the grey value that you want.

This will work for `uint16` images as well, since you can use `uint64` to aggregate the data.

For larger `K`, you can take a completely different approach:

1. Pass the raveled `idata` through `np.unique` with `return_inverse=True`. This will give you an array of sorted unique values, and an index that will replace them into image order.
2. Run `np.searchsorted` to place `ipalette` into the unique values.
3. Discard any in indices that don't represent an exact match.
4. Replace the exact matches with the grey values.
5. Rebuild the image from the unique values with grey replacements.

Something like this:

```
uniques, reverse_index = np.unique(idata.ravel(), return_inverse=True)
palette_index = np.searchsorted(uniques, ipalette)
# clipping won't affect the match but avoids errors
palette_mask = (ipalette == uniques[palette_index.clip(0, uniques.size - 1)])
uniques[palette_index[palette_mask]] = igrey[palette_mask]
new_data = uniques[reverse_index].view(np.uint8).reshape(data.shape)
```

Here is a full working example of the first method:

```
np.random.seed(0)
data = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(100, 100, 4), dtype=np.uint8)
palette = np.array([[117, 166,  22, 183],
                    [ 38,  28,  93, 140],
                    [ 63, 214,   9,  84],
                    [185,  51,   1,  24],
                    [131, 210, 145,   3],
                    [111, 180, 165, 245],
                    [ 62, 220, 102, 144],
                    [177,  97, 158, 135],
                    [202,  67, 169,  10],
                    [ 23, 177,  26,  15],
                    [ 19, 100,  25,  66],
                    [ 86, 227, 222, 182],
                    [255, 255, 255, 255]], dtype=np.uint8)
grey = np.arange(10, 10 + len(palette), dtype=np.uint8)

idata = data.view(np.uint32)
ipalette = palette.view(np.uint32).squeeze()
igrey = np.repeat(grey[:, None], data.shape[-1], axis=-1).view(np.uint32).squeeze()

ind = np.nonzero(idata == ipalette)
idata[ind[0], ind[1], 0] = igrey[ind[-1]]
```

I've selected the palette to be the pixels that are displayed with my default settings when I do `>>> data`, just so that you can immediately see that the method works.

With the second method, you can see that clipping makes it possible to have the value 0xFFFFFFFF in the palette, which gets and insertion index greater than the size of the array, without crashing or having to introduce any special cases.

Comment: Thanks. Merging the colours to produce a single (larger) number is a nice idea and although I still don't really understand how the `view` thing works, it's certainly a cool trick. However, the rest of the approach doesn't seem to work, at least the idea of using `idata == palette`. In my computer it raises a warning, and returns an empty array: `DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future`. And what's the rationale for two different approaches depending on the value of `K`?

Comment: @Onturenio. That particular error was caused by the typo `idata == ipalette` was the correct expression. I've fixed a number of other problems in the answer that came about from writing on mobile without testing. Let me know if it works for you now.

Comment: It does. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Onturenio. Which approach did you end up using?

Comment: First option, as in my case K=11.

Answer (score 1):

When I compare your solution with this one:

```
for i in range(palette.shape[0]):
    new_data[data == palette[i]] = grey_palette[i]
```

using `%%timeit` in a notebook gives 87ms vs 218ms for yours for a 1000x1000x3 `data`.

EDIT: deleted comment about a 'problem' with your solution that I created by changing to `new_data` only in one place.

Comment: But this doesn't work as requested, right? I do not want to change each channel independently. For the colour to be equal, all channels must be simultaneously equal within the pixel (this is why I used the three '&'). Your solution will change (and mess) colours when ANY of the channels is equal to the corresponding channel in one of the colours in `palette`. Right?

Comment: For RGB data, this sets R = G = B = grey value. I didn't deal with the alpha value as it seems like you want to preserve it. You could either save it somewhere and concatenate it, or add two lines:
`match = (data == palette[i])`, then
`match[:,:,-1] = False`, and finally 
`new_data[match] = grey_palette[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary `d` build from you palettes `{palette[i]: grey_palette[i]}` (completed by trivial entries `{i:i}` otherwise), vectorize it and apply to your data

```
numpy.vectorize(d.get)(data)
```

It should be fast but I have not tested it with your type of data.

Comment: I'm not so fluent in Python, but `palette[i]` is not a string, but an array of shape(4,). How can it be the key of a dictionary?

Comment: There will be no problem if the dictionary is built like this: `d = {}`, then the identity loop `d[x] = x` (for all possible values `x` in your `data` to avoid mapping execution errors) and finally your specific mapping `d[palette[i]] = grey_palette[i]`. 
If there is a problem with the shape of `palette[i]` it must be transformed before to something simpler what dict can deal with. It cannot deal with arrays but it can with tuples, e.g. `d[(1,2,3)] = 99`, so your data can be simply transformed like that.